# PHP AJAX Live Search: display all possible matches

Tags: php, ajax, livesearch

I integrated the [live search script of W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) on a website and it works well. However, it only shows exact matches.

For example in the demo, if you type "CSS border", you will get "CSS border Property". This is fine. However, if you search "CSS Property", no suggestion will appear.

Is it possible to modify their script so it shows all results containing the same words, regardless of the order?

Comment: is it possible for you to show the code you have?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. The code is the same of the code available on the [page of W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use mysql fulltext indexes, then use natural language match queries as follows:

```
SELECT 
  `your_fulltext_indexed_field`, 
  MATCH (`your_fulltext_indexed_field`) AGAINST ('Your Search Phrase' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS match_score
FROM 
  `your_table` 
WHERE 
  MATCH (`your_fulltext_indexed_field`) AGAINST ('Your Search Phrase' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

The provided example will eliminate records with no match and order the results from most relevant to least relevant.
You can find detailed description [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) in mysql official documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help! Do you think it would be possible to do that without a database? I am currently using an XML file and no database.

Comment: The other way is to use regular expressions, but it will be much more complicated compared to database option.
Here are some useful links to check:
[Regex playground](https://regex101.com/) and [PHP's preg_match function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)